# Quartz.Net passing and returning data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, quartz.net

Just find out about Quartz.Net, but having some problem to retrieve any data from Job. Here's is my code:

```
    protected static void ConfigureQuartzJobs()
    {
        // construct a scheduler factory
        ISchedulerFactory schedFact = new StdSchedulerFactory();

        // get a scheduler
        IScheduler sched = schedFact.GetScheduler();
        sched.Start();

        IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<ServerStatusJob>()
            .WithIdentity("myJob", "group1") // name "myJob", group "group1"
            .UsingJobData("xxx", "param1")
            .Build();

        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
          .WithIdentity("myTrigger", "group1")
          .StartNow()
          .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
              .WithIntervalInSeconds(30)
              .RepeatForever())
          .Build();

        sched.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
    }
```

Above code I ran in my Application_Start(). As you can see, I try to pass my some data 'xxx'.

```
public class MyJob : IJob
{
    public void Execute(Quartz.IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        JobKey key = context.JobDetail.Key;
        JobDataMap dataMap = context.JobDetail.JobDataMap;

        string jobSays = dataMap.GetString("xxx");

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Run at " + jobSays + DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }
}
```

At this point, I successfully get the parameter I just sent. But how do I return back some data to my ConfigureQuartzJobs() method.

Comment: Please explain what kind of data you want to return, why and where. It doesn't really make sense to do so, especially since your Configure method has returned already. Try reading about the Jobstore, or persist job data yourself, for example using a database.

Comment: yeah your right, it already returned. I'm having a trouble getting my nhibernate session in the Execute() method. Not sure how to get it.

Answer (score 1):

You can save data this way. (see below)
But you're not "returning it" to the ConfigureQuartzJobs method.
That method simply wires up everything.

http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/more-about-jobs.html

*PersistJobDataAfterExecution is an attribute that can be added to the Job class that tells Quartz to update the stored copy of the JobDetail's JobDataMap after the Execute() method completes successfully (without throwing an exception), such that the next execution of the same job (JobDetail) receives the updated values rather than the originally stored values. Like the DisallowConcurrentExecution attribute, this applies to a job definition instance, not a job class instance, though it was decided to have the job class carry the attribute because it does often make a difference to how the class is coded (e.g. the 'statefulness' will need to be explicitly 'understood' by the code within the execute method).*

Comment: Thanks for the info. But do you know how can I get my Nhibernate session inside the Execute() method? Really having trouble to retrieve the session.